# Convert object to byte array and viceversa without serialization

Tags: java, serialization, object, arrays

I have a java project in which I have to save the data of each run for later use. The professor wants us to use a RandomAccessFile to do this so I have to convert the objects to bytes so they can be stored in the RAF. The major problem is that if we use Serializable he'll deduct points,so my question is:

Is there a way to convert object to byte array and viceversa without serialization?

I don't want a full code just an approach to on how to do it is appreciated.

EDIT:

Thank you all for the advice, I ended up converting the objects fields to bytes and writing that to the RAF.

Comment: Did your professor limit the scope of this to Objects containing simple values, such as byte, int, long and String or any Object can be contained?

Comment: Have you looked at JAXB? Marhsalling/unmarshalling mechanism is an alternative way to save and restore object state without serialization.

Comment: @mazaneicha, I don't think that'as really in the spirit of the assignment.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen - How do you know? Oh!... The mystery professor deducting points for using java.io.serializable revealed! :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write primitives and a few objects (Strings, byte arrays, and boxed primitives like Boolean and Integer which will be unboxed) directly to the RAF.  If you have a larger object, break it into something RAF can accept.  For example, if you have a list of strings, loop over them and write each with [writeUTF](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29).  Remember that you have to read it back in, so you'll have to use some kind of headers.  For example, you'll probably want to write the length of the list before the elements.

Comment: "You should be able to write most objects directly to the RAF." How? With which method?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `Serializable` on the class, you've to find all the fields of the object using [Reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

After that you can follow the suggestion of Matthew Flashen to write those field values to your RandomAccessFile.

Comment: I wouldn't use reflection for this.  The OP is not required to save / restore *any* object ... just instances of certain application specific classes.

Comment: @StephenC I think you're right. The original poster should clarify this. Of course if the Class structure is already known, there is no need to develop a general solution, which would be much more complicated, especially for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe xml is a good idea to represent object in text format. You can give each object an unique id and use `<ref>id</ref>` to show the relationships.